# Google Now option "Contact recognition" is not visible on my HTC One (M7)

Tags: contacts, google-now, htc-one, lg-g-watch-r

I have a HTC One (M7) and just purchased an LG G Watch R. The combination is working fine, except for the fact that my contacts are not recognized when speaking via "OK, Google".

I wrote a mail to HTC, they told me it's an LG issue. I wrote a mail to LG, they tell me it's the fault of HTC. I have no idea anymore what to do.

In Google Now, going to Accounts & Privacy should have an option "Contact recognition", between items "Safesearch Filter" and "Search engine storage". I don't have this option.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Google settings -> search & now -> accounts & privacy

Comment: Bob, please read through my text. It almost clearly says this is the place I have been into all the time...

Comment: An anonymous user edited this in : "I had this same problem. Turns out I was doing it from the settings on my m7 and from the Google app. When I tried it from Google now it worked."